# How is "propositional canonicity" useful?

Tags: canonicity

I know that canonicity implies that all closed terms can be computed into a term generated by introduction rules, but people (I forgot who) told me about "propositional canonicity", where all closed terms can be computed to a term that is *propositionally equivalent to* a term generated by introduction rules. Does this property have any interesting consequences/corollaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there are two main uses of canonicity.

The first one is that it is a way to prove consistency, because you have no introduction for `False`, so you cannot have a proof of it in the empty context because that proof would need to be convertible to the non-existing introduction.
This you keep with propositional consistency: if you have a closed proof of `False`, then this proof must be propositionally equal to an introduction, of which again there are none.

The second is to somehow characterise that your conversion is "strong enough". This is softer, but in terms of reduction it usually means that you have a form of progress (every term is either an introduction, stuck on a variable, or reduces), so in practice you do not get too much stuck terms and your conversion is powerful enough to solve quite some goals.
If you have propositional canonicity instead, you lose that, and might now get much more stuck terms. But you still know that while you cannot use conversion too reliably, you can at least reason propositionally and that this is "strong enough" again.

Comment: Thanks very much!